# Is avoiding prototype declaration for private function (defined before its use) a MISRA violation?

Tags: c, coding-style, function-prototypes, function-declaration, misra

Making prototype declaration for all functions defined in a C file is considered as a good programming. It also satisfies MISRA guideline.
But I have seen developers ignoring prototype declarations for functions which are defined before it's used - It seems prototype declaration is unnecessary in such cases.

So can somebody please tell me if it's a MISRA violation ?

Comment: As has been mentioned, yes, it is a violation.  The rule itself, however, is formulated too broad, though: For static functions that are defined before they are used all problems mentioned by MISRA as justification for the rule do not apply.  I mention it since in this particular case I don't consider creation of a prototype good programming practice, but unnecessary maintenance burden.  A better formulation for a rule would go in the direction, that wherever a function is called, at least a prototype declaration or the definition of that function must have been seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule 8.1 of MISRA 2004 says that

> Functions shall have prototype declarations and the prototype shall be visible at both the function definition and call.

The explanation given is as follows

> The use of prototypes enables the compiler to check the integrity of function definitions and calls. Without prototypes the compiler is not obliged to pick up certain errors in function calls. (e.g. different number of arguments from the function body, mismatch in types of arguments between call and definition).
>
> Function interfaces have been shown to be a cause of considerable
> problems, and therefore this rule is considered very important.

So, yes, you would voilate MISRA

Comment: Not sure the copyright of MISRA rules allows to cut'n'paste content here. The one I linked is clearly infringing the copyright.

Comment: @Bruce Generally I doubt they mind if you cite individual rules, I would rather think they'd encourage it. Anyway, I don't think copyright is a good reason for posting link-only answers.

Comment: @Lundin : I agree that link-only is bad, I did it only this time because of the copyright reason. I'm always hesitating when the question is explicitly on material with limited diffusion rules

Answer (score 1):

It's breaking the rule 8.1 of misra C: http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/468328/misra-c-2004.pdf